# Identify List VBA

Tags: excel, vba, list, counting

I have 3 lists, called 'List1','List2' and 'List3'

My lists sit on the face of the spreadsheet (Worksheet1). (They not in a separate form). They were created from the ActiveX collection of tools.

What code/object name identifies Lists such as mine.

Here is what I have tried:

> Set wrksht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
>
> n1 =wrksht.ListObjects.Count
>
> n2 = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes.Count
>
> n3 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Count

When I step through the code, n1, n2 and n3 allcome out as 0 (no error message is generated), which means VBA 'recognizes' something. But value I expect is 3, so the object reference is wrong.

So what object should I be using.

Comment: It doesn't recognize anything really. It just counts the amount of tables AKA ListObjects on your worksheet. If there are none, it will output `0` as per your result.

Comment: `ListObjects` are tables. `ListBoxes` are Form Control list boxes.

Comment: *They were created from the ActiveX collection of tools* ListObjects, as far as I know, are not ActiveX objects, because they are tables. I think you are using a different control, not a ListObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something along these lines, calling like so `countshapes("ListBox")`

```
Function CountShapes(strType As String) As Long

Dim s As Shapes
Dim shp As Shape

Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes

For Each shp In s

    If shp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then

        If TypeName(shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object) = strType Then
            CountShapes = CountShapes + 1
        End If

    End If

Next shp

End Function
```

Comment: Now that I can identify the shape, can I do anything with it? There is a list that contains Days of the week. I want the user to select, and me to be able to read the selection. Here is another approach to identifying the OLE object, but I still cannot read (or even 'see' programmatically) the list:
`code`

For Each obj In Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects

 aval = obj.Name

 obj.Select

'but I cannot do anything with the obj
Next
`code`

Comment: You would need to add `Dim l As MSForms.ListBox` and then when the count is incremented, `Set l = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object`.  Note, it would be best to make this listbox only to avoid errors too.